# Using Hibernate annotations to persist custom value for Enumerated attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have lots of Java enums that I persist with Hibernate. As far as I know there are two different standard ways to persist these enums:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
```

This is the default, and it just persists the ordinal value from the enum.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

This persists the name of the enum value.

Those have worked fine for me so far, but now I have a new enum where I want to persist a custom value from the enum that is neither the ordinal nor the name. Is this possible? I searched around and saw lots of people asking how to persist the name, which is easily accomplished using EnumType.STRING, but I want to persist an int that can be used for comparison in my SQL queries. I tried overriding toString() to return my custom value, but that did not work.

I'll paste my java enum below. I want to persist the int value member from the enum.

Thanks in advance!

```
public enum Permission {
    VIEW (4),
    CHANGE(6),
    FULL(7);

    private int value;

    Permission(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I'm missing a JPA solution, too.

Workaround:

```
  private int permissionValue;
  private transient Permission permission;
```

Then convert in the getter/setter of permission.

Maybe you also need to implement some lifecycle methods? (I'm not sure.)
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/undejbs003.htm#BABIAAGE

Answer (score 5):

You can implement a `UserType` with desired behaviour and configure Hibernate to use it with [`@Type`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e2794) annotation.

See, for example, [UserType for persisting a Typesafe Enumeration with a VARCHAR column](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeforpersistingaTypesafeEnumerationwithaVARCHARcolumn)
.

Comment: Yes, but sadly not portable across JPA implementations.

Comment: Thanks. A hibernate-only solution is fine for me, but I'd rather do it with annotations. That example uses a mapping file. Can the same thing be done with annotations? If so, how?

Comment: @Ike: Note the link in the first paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Okay, I see that now. Thanks! I ended up going with the workaround suggested by Puce because it was simpler to implement, but I'll keep this in mind in the future.