# How to translate name for @Enumerated properties?

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa

There are two EnumType: as `EnumType.ORDINAL` and as `EnumType.STRING`. However both have disvantages:

```
EnumType.ORDINAL: You must preserve the enum order.

EnumType.STRING: The column width is the max length of the enum names, which maybe very long.
```

Instead, I'd like to introduce an abbreviation for the enum type:

```
public Enum MonthEnum {
    January("JAN"),
    February("FEB"),
    March("MAR"),
    ...;

    String abbrev;

    static Map<String, MonthEnum> abbrevs = new HashMap();

    MonthEnum(String abbrev) {
        this.abbrev = abbrev;
        abbrevs.put(abbrev, this);
    }

    public static MonthEnum fromAbbrev(String abbrev) {
        return abbrevs.get(abbrev);
    }
}

@Entity
class Diary {
    @Enumerated(ABBREV)
    Month month;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Hibernate annotations to persist custom value for Enumerated attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032116/using-hibernate-annotations-to-persist-custom-value-for-enumerated-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done in JPA 2.0. But it can be done in Hibernate using UserType. But why would you want to. I have considered your argument for the string variant, but wouldnt this argument apply to any string (varchar) column in a database. Please also consider that the enum will probably be used in the JAVA code so a long enum string value would also be a problem there.